# MassTransit. Edit MessageType property for remove unnecessary items

Tags: .net-core, microservices, azureservicebus, masstransit

First of all, excuse my English, it's very bad. I am using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus for asynchronous communication between microservices.

Due to project design requirements, the objects sent and / or published in masstransit are objects (class instances) that implement interfaces and have inheritance, which implies that the "MessageType" property is an array of multiple values, which results in a sending/publication of "a copy" of the object for each of the base classes and interfaces of the object.

Since the application really only needs to process the final class, the result of this behavior is that queues and topics of message types are created that are never processed.

Is there a way to modify the MessageType array to remove all unnecessary items?

Example:

This is a current message:

```
{
  "messageId": "c93e0000-eab0-3663-c954-08d89e1f87cb",
  "correlationId": "42fc2237-77b1-4994-821d-87790b6caf06",
  "conversationId": "c93e0000-eab0-3663-f342-08d89e1f87cd",
  "sourceAddress": "sb://bus.servicebus.windows.net/tmspayments7dc9d65778jfh75_dotnet_bus_3r9yyy8ksy5g84tdbdcjasmhg9",
  "destinationAddress": "sb://bus.servicebus.windows.net/queue",
  "messageType": [
    "urn:message:Payments.Application.Integration.Outcoming.Commands.Sales:NotifySalePaymentHasCanceledCommand",
    "urn:message:Payments.Application.Integration.Outcoming.Commands:BaseIntegrationOutcomingCommand",
    "urn:message:Tms.Frameworks.CqrsEs.Cqrs.Commands:IdentifiedCommandBase",
    "urn:message:Tms.Frameworks.CqrsEs.Cqrs.Messages:MessageBase",
    "urn:message:Tms.Frameworks.CqrsEs.Cqrs.Messages:IIdentifiedMessage",
    "urn:message:Tms.Frameworks.CqrsEs.Cqrs.Messages:IMessage",
    "urn:message:Tms.Frameworks.CqrsEs.Cqrs.Commands:IIdentifiedCommand",
    "urn:message:Tms.Frameworks.CqrsEs.Cqrs.Messages:ICommand",
    "urn:message:Tms.Frameworks.CqrsEs.Cqrs.Commands.Outcoming:IOutcomingCommand",
    "urn:message:Tms.Frameworks.CqrsEs.Cqrs.Messages:IOutcomingMessage"
  ],
  "message": {
    "commandId": "42fc2237-77b1-4994-821d-87790b6caf06",
    "terminalId": 71,
    "paymentId": "a28a23e9-3ba5-464f-9a20-d25d1991ab46"
  },
  "sentTime": "2020-12-11T21:55:53.252599Z",
  "headers": {},
  "host": {
    "machineName": "tms-payments-7dc9d65778-jfh75",
    "processName": "dotnet",
    "processId": 1,
    "assembly": "Payments.Api",
    "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "frameworkVersion": "3.1.8",
    "massTransitVersion": "5.5.2.0",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "Unix 4.15.0.1098"
  }
}
```

And this is my goal message (with only one item in messageType property):

```
{
  "messageId": "c93e0000-eab0-3663-c954-08d89e1f87cb",
  "correlationId": "42fc2237-77b1-4994-821d-87790b6caf06",
  "conversationId": "c93e0000-eab0-3663-f342-08d89e1f87cd",
  "sourceAddress": "sb://bus.servicebus.windows.net/tmspayments7dc9d65778jfh75_dotnet_bus_3r9yyy8ksy5g84tdbdcjasmhg9",
  "destinationAddress": "sb://bus.servicebus.windows.net/queue",
  "messageType": [
    "urn:message:Payments.Application.Integration.Outcoming.Commands.Sales:NotifySalePaymentHasCanceledCommand"
  ],
  "message": {
    "commandId": "42fc2237-77b1-4994-821d-87790b6caf06",
    "terminalId": 71,
    "paymentId": "a28a23e9-3ba5-464f-9a20-d25d1991ab46"
  },
  "sentTime": "2020-12-11T21:55:53.252599Z",
  "headers": {},
  "host": {
    "machineName": "tms-payments-7dc9d65778-jfh75",
    "processName": "dotnet",
    "processId": 1,
    "assembly": "Payments.Api",
    "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "frameworkVersion": "3.1.8",
    "massTransitVersion": "5.5.2.0",
    "operatingSystemVersion": "Unix 4.15.0.1098"
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Regards

Borja

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: No

MassTransit will reflect all supported types and include them in the message envelope to support polymorphic message delivery and deserialization.

You can [exclude message types](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.0.4.html#rabbitmq-azure-service-bus) from being created as exchanges/topics on the message broker, but that does not exclude them from the message type array during serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Some more questions:
- Is this attribute inheritable? If to a class 'A' that implements interface 'B', and it implements interface 'C', if I put the attribute on interface 'C', interface 'B' is excluded?

- If the attribute is put in a class 'A' that is later published / sent, the topic of class 'A' is created anyway?

Thank you so much for your time Chris!

Regards

Comment: No, it is not inherited. That would effectively make it useless since it would exclude entire type hierarchies, instead of just the specific type.